# @ sign in python method call

Tags: python, methods

I am new to python and saw the following code in an example

```
import functools
...
..

def wrapper(func):
            @functools.wraps(func)
            ....
```

What does the @ sign mean here?

Answer (score 1):

That is the syntax for [Python decorators](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/)--functions or methods that can take an object, say a function, method or class, and perform something when the object is being called or when it's returning a result.

Answer (score 0):

You're leaving out an important part from the example. A similar one can be found in the [official `functools.wrap` doc](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functools.html#functools.wraps), and looks like:

```
from functools import wraps
def my_decorator(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwds):
        print('Calling decorated function')
        return f(*args, **kwds)
    return wrapper
```

In this example, the names are a little mixed up in respect to yours. In this one `@wraps(f)` is decorating the function `wrapper` (the one that comes right after).

There are a lot of source around about what Python decorators are. [Here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators)'s one of them.

Comment: I have overseen that the decorator decorates the wrapper function. I have coded a few examples and now it is clear. Thank you!